# Terraform error EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name iam_for_lambda already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I run the command `terraform apply` the following error occurred because the role already exists:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role iam_for_lambda: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name iam_for_lambda already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: 204c6c00-0b1d-4fb9-bf9c-fca48c67d669

  on main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda":
   1: resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
```

Can I use trick to check, without errors, if the role already exists?

Comment: Ideally, you would create the IAM role that you need in this template so its life cycle is the same as the underlying stack. Or, if you need to support an existing role, then it would be an input parameter to the template and it would have a life cycle independent of the stack.

Comment: Are you trying to manage an IAM role that already exists?

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes, I should create IAM role if not exists, otherwise create them via terraform resource

Comment: @LorenzoD'Isidoro you could import the resource to Terraform state, and them apply. More info in [official doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#import)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you worked this out yourself, since the question is a year old, but if the resource exists for legitimate reasons, you can have your code take ownership by importing it:

```sh
terraform import aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda iam_for_lambda
```

Now, when you run Terraform, it will think it already created the resource, and if you update your code, the rolle gets the updates too.

That being said, you should probably not try to create a role that already exists. Even if you use `terraform import` to take ownership of the resource, you might get odd results if your code is modifying a role that is also owned by another module.